# OpenSSL subject from .cert different than .csr

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ca

I received an external .csr from a server that wishes to use my CA to receive back the .cert file. It is required to have the serialNumber field in the .cert subject.

By checking the .csr I can see the serialNumber present in the Subject field:

```
openssl req -in mycert.csr.pem -noout -text
```

```
Certificate Request:
    Data:
        Version: 1 (0x0)
        Subject: serialNumber = 1710128, CN = central.superserver.com.br
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
      ...
```

But, when I generate the certificate using the `openssl ca` command, the serialNumber field is gone from the subject

```
openssl ca -config openssl.cnf       
-extensions server_sign_cert -days 375 -notext -md sha256 -in mycert.csr.pem -out mycert.cert.pem
```

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 4108 (0x100c)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul 28 17:49:41 2019 GMT
            Not After : Aug  6 17:49:41 2020 GMT
        Subject: CN = central.superserver.com.br
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
        ...
```

Is there any way to keep the Subject on the Certificate file in the same way as received from the CSR?

Answer (score 1):

DN Fields to be included in the output certificate have to be listed in the **policy** section of the openssl configuration file (any fields not mentioned in the policy section are silently discarded). See the man page of **openssl** **ca** command and search for **-policy** and "**POLICY FORMAT**" sections for the details.